# Mudar ações de um único botão com javascript

Tags: javascript

Boa dia pessoal,

Tenho um código html de página unica onde controlo a visualização de 3 divs com exibir/ocultar através de um menu.

Porém gostaria de utilizar um único botão onde conforme cada div for exibida ele tivesse uma ação diferente. Ex:

```
DIV 1 ativada
function botão() {        
abreHome();
}

DIV 2 ativada
function botão() {        
abreCatalogo();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando jQuery você consegue facilmente alterar o label ou a funcionalidade de um botão quando um evento é disparado (no seu caso, quando o `div` tiver a visibilidade alterada, ou algo assim).

Segue um exemplo usando o collapse do Bootstrap:

```js
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")
var colaps = $("#collapseExample")

colaps.on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
  button.html("Abrir link");
  //altere aqui a funcionalidade tb...
})
colaps.on("hide.bs.collapse", function(){
  button.html("Mudar cor");
})
button.on("click", function(){
  banner.addClass("alt")
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
Mostrar painel
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
<div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-header">Botão alterado!</div>
<div class="card-body">
  <p class="card-text">O valor do botão foi alterado, e agora ele possui novo título. Você também pode alterar sua funcionalidade.</p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Mudar cor</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado utilizei exatamente seu código, funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 0):

Tenta algo assim

```js
const changeAction = (t) => {

const action = t.getAttribute('data-action')

return actions[action](t)

}

const actions = {
 acaoUm: (t) =>{
 console.log('Acão um');
 t.setAttribute('data-action', 'acaoDois')
 
 
 },
 acaoDois: (t) =>{
  console.log('Acão dois');
 t.setAttribute('data-action', 'acaoUm')
 
 },

}
```

```html
<div>
<span onclick="changeAction(this)" data-action="acaoUm">
um
</span>

</span>
</div>
```

Não manjo muito de publicar no slack..mas fiz um ex aqui [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/hernanimattos/yops3wxd/17/)

Comment: Tente explicar melhor sua resposta.

Comment: Acho que viajei ai na solução é pra ser um botão só..deu ruim ai..rs..Com um botão o teria que fazer algum contador que a cada click mude a classe ou um attr do elemento html..

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Hernani, consegui a solução com o que o gcpdev publicou